# How to match a substring surrounded by known prefix and suffix in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string, such as:

> example string with an intended nested string to match.

How to isolate a substring knowing only a prefix and suffix for it, e.g. between `intended` and `to match`?

Answer (score 14):

Use regular expressions with [non-capturing parentheses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters), like so:

```
string = 'example string with an intended nested string to match.';
regexp = /(?:intended)(.*)(?:to match)/;
firstMatch = regexp.exec(string)[1]; // " nested string "
```

The question mark has several uses in regular expressions, the parentheses question mark colon form `(?:`*more regex*`)` is the [non-capturing parentheses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters).

See MDN for more details of [exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), string.[match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), and [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Look behind `(?<=`...`)` and look ahead `(?=`...`)` can be used to the same effect -- they are used to match but are not included in the result, the term for that behavior is referred to as *"not consuming"*

[RegExp Lookahead Lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind)

```
/(?<=intended).+(?=to match)/g;
```

[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/ux9uTp/1)

```js
const str = `example string with an intended nested string to match.`;

const rgx = /(?<=intended).+(?=to match)/g;

const hit = str.match(rgx);

console.log(hit[0]);
```